# Ploty no muestra la gráfica

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, plotly

Acabo de crear un entorno nuevo con conda (python 3.8) y he instalado ploty (5.10.0).

El código siguiente

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import talib as tb
import pandas as pd

#  SMA usando Talib
SMA = tb.SMA(df_close['Close'], timeperiod=200)

# Crear un DataFrame df_sma con la columna 'SMA'
df_sma = pd.DataFrame(index=df_close.index)  # Asegúrate de que el índice coincida
df_sma['SMA'] = SMA
# Trim the SMA DataFrame to the same length as the close DataFrame
df_sma = df_sma.iloc[:len(df_close)]


# Create a Plotly Figure object
fig = go.Figure()

# Add the time series data as a line trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df_close.index,
        y=df_close['Close'],
        mode='lines',
        name='Price',
        line=dict(color='green', width=1.5),
    )
)

# Add the SMA as a line trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df_sma.index,
        y=df_sma['SMA'],
        mode='lines',
        name=value_name,
        line=dict(color='blue', width=0.5),
    )
)

# Update the layout of the plot
fig.update_layout(
    title=f'SMA of {value_name}',
    xaxis=dict(title=f'{start_date} - {end_date}', showgrid=True),
    yaxis=dict(title=f'Close Price {value_name}', showgrid=True),
    legend=dict(x=0, y=1, traceorder='normal'),
    plot_bgcolor='white',
    showlegend=True,
)

# Display the plot
fig.show()
```

No muestra ninguna gráfica. Pruebo con plotly.express.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Calculate the SMA
SMA = tb.SMA(df_close['Close'], timeperiod=200)

# Trim the SMA DataFrame to the same length as the close DataFrame
df_sma = df_sma.iloc[:len(df_close)]

# Plot the data
value_name = 'Stock Price'  # Replace with actual value name

fig = px.line(df_close, x=df_close.index, y='Close', title=f'Price of {value_name}')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_sma.index, y=df_sma['SMA'], mode='lines', name=value_name, line=dict(color='blue', width=0.5)))
fig.show()
```

Tampoco muestra la gráfica.

Localizo y abro con nano, el archivo  '.bashrc' y le añado al final la ruta a ploty 'export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/enri/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plotly'.
Grabo y cierro. vuelvo la notebook y ejecuto los scripts, comprobando que continúo en la misma situación. Agradeceré sugerencias para resolver este problema.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). El código mostrado tiene muchas variables que no han sido definidas y no se puede reproducir el problema, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega la información faltante.

Comment: Cuando tu ejecutas codigo en anaconda, los graficos e imagenes generadas en codigos en este IDLE se muestran en una ventana arriba a la derecha en el mismo IDLE. Esta modalidad de visualizacion se configura en spyder y te permite elegir entre mostra imagen en esa ventana o en una ventana emergente.
Lo mas probable es que s{i se esten generando tus graficas pero no este configurado la ventana emergente si no que mostrar en la ventana del IDLE.